# How to call a service created in Android Studio from an application created in Expo

Tags: android, expo

I developed a service to print on a device with a built-in printer but when calling or invoking this service from an application developed in Expo it does not work

The purpose is that the service can be called or invoked from an application developed in Expo, the call or incovation from the Expo application must be explicit (I do not know if this is possible in Expo), unfortunately I do not have the code for the Expo application since It is from other developers who are trying to integrate this functionality of printing on the device, but I share the AndroidManifest.xml file of my service, I hope you can help me, thank you for your time.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testintentcencosud">

    <!--- permissions I tried previously for another error I had -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    
    <!--- permissions required for the service -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestIntentCencosud"
        tools:targetApi="31" >

        <service android:name=".Servicio"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Add that I tested this service by creating another application in Android Studio which is made up of a button that when pressed sends the intent and it worked correctly